# Error 500--Internal Server Error - Oracle Webgate Configuration

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

Environment:

- Oracle 11g database
- Weblogic 11.3.6
- Webgate 3
- Forms&reports 11 g (11.1.2.0)
- WebTier 11.1.1.9.0

Problem :

When trying to access form with :

`http://localhost:7777/forms/frmservlet`

i have this error:

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

but when i set `ssoMode = false` in `formsweb.cfg` froms's config file, the forms welcome page displays well.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: ssoMode is used to define Single Sign-On, what middleware program do you have to authenticate the user? OAM and OID are one way this can be accomplished with Oracle technologies.

Answer (score 0):

> **ssoMode** (`Single Sign-On parameter`) indicates whether the *URL* is
>   protected in which case `mod_osso`, which is *Oracle Single Sign-On
>   Module*, will be given control for authentication or continue in  the
>   *FormsServlet* if not.

It is *false* by default. It may be set to *true* in an
 application-specific section to enable *Single Sign-On* for that application.

*formsweb.cfg*,in which *ssoMode* parameter may also be overridden , defines parameter values used by the *FormsServlet* (`frmservlet`)

> The **mod_osso** component is a module that plugs into Oracle HTTP
>   Server. It enables the HTTP listener as a partner application that can
>   use the Single Sign-On server to authenticate users. Once mod_osso is
>   installed and configured, Web applications can register URLs that
>   require SSO authentication with the module. Then when URL requests are
>   received by the HTTP server, mod_osso detects which requests require
>   SSO authentication and redirects them to the Single Sign-On server.
>   After the Single Sign-On server authenticates the user, it passes the
>   user's authenticated identity back to mod_osso in a secure token, or
>   cookie. The module retrieves the user's identity from the cookie and
>   propagates the user's identity information to applications running in
>   the HTTP server instance. The module can propagate the user's identity
>   information to applications running in the CGI, those running in
>   Oracle9iAS Containers for J2EE, and it can also authenticate users for
>   access to static files.
>
> Oracle Forms Services applications can be run in a single sign-on
>   (SSO) environment using Oracle Login Server (Single Sign-On Server)
>   and Oracle Internet Directory (OID) to store user name and password
>   information. For Single Sign-On implementation Oracle Forms is
>   considered as an 'External Application'.

In *Forms*, it is possible to obtain the *Single Sign-On* username via :

```
GET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY(sso_userid);
```

This returns a string containing the Single Sign On user ID if the user has been authenticated via the Login Server. A NULL value is returned if SSO was not used.

It is possible to also obtain the user distinguished name (dn) and the subscriber distinguished name (subscriber dn) e.g.

```
GET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY(sso_usrdn);
GET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY(sso_subdn);
```